# view/page specific javascript(coffeescript) in rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

I've searched over and over again on how I should be organizing my code in the asset pipeline and I noticed that several people asked about this in different ways as well yet I still can't find the answer I am looking so I hope this question would shed some light....

My Javascript code in assets/javascripts originally goes something like this:

```
jQuery ->
    function1 = () ->
    function2 = () ->
    function3 = () ->
    function4 = () ->
    ...
    functionN = () ->
```

It was getting pretty messy and unreadable and since some parts of the code is page specific I tried to refactor it:

```
jQuery ->
    function1 = () ->
    function2 = () ->
    ...
    functionN = () ->
    if $('#id_for_show').length
        function3a = () ->
        function4a = () ->
    if $('#id_for_index').length
        function3a = () ->
        function4a = () ->
```

the two different views (show & index) share both function1 & 2 but the code for each will obviously be for a specific page.

My question is, is this the proper way?? Is there a much cleaner way of doing this?

Below is what I tried to do which obviously didn't work.

I tried to separate the my code into three files and add it to the manifest like so:

```
assets/javascripts/restaurant/show/show.js.coffeescript => first if statement
assets/javascripts/restaurant/index/index.js.coffeescript => second if statement
assets/javascripts/restaurant/restaurant.js.coffeescript => functions that are shared

...
require_path ./restaurant
```

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Your paths for assets are weird. Put the file 'show.js.coffeescript' under 'app/assets/javascripts/restaurant/show/' folder and try this format in a view or layout:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag('restaurant/show/show') %>
```

You could also add a condition:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag('restaurant/show/show') if condition %>
```

Comment: so I added <%= javascript_include_tag('restaurant/show/show') %> in my  restaurant/show view and it's still not working....